# hibernate entity mapping null object

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a hibernate mapping ,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{


@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="email_id",nullable=true)
private Email email;

}
```

In my mapping , the Email object will be null sometimes. Am getting below error , since the email_id and email fields are not null , I want to insert only on User table , need to skip the Email table if the object is null. How do I handle this scenario ?

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

if I use **`@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL), am getting null exception`** .

Please help me  ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have email_id in the same object (`user`) and if you wish `Email` table to be read only then you don't your email to be persisted.

Comment: No , I need this Email Object to be separated , I cant use this inside the User Object, Since sometimes the Email object will be inserted.

Comment: @user1335605, I am not saying you to keep all attributes in `user`. Just keep `email_id` as property in `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could complement your [`@JoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html?is-external=true) annotation with the [`referencedColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()) options to specify the PK column of Email.